# PHP search funtion makes my website collapse

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, dynamic

Im just creating a webpage with search feature and in every search i have a database query that brings back suggestions. But when i fire this onkeyup fucntion too many times (I mean 10-20 time) because its getting fired again and again while tryping, after too many firing website colapses and gives me an error page, standart google chore error page (not the php error pages that explain whats wrong) after 1 minute, everything goes normal. Do you have any idea?

Thank You.

Here is my JS Code

```
    var timer;
    $('#search').keyup(function(e){
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var searchname = $('#search').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"php/fetchsuggest.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{searchname:searchname},
            success: function(data){
                $('#fetch').show();
                $('#fetch').html(data);

                //select fetch as val
                $('.fetched').click(function(){
                    var innerval=$(this).text();
                    $('#search').val(innerval);
                    $('#fetch').hide();
                    $('#search').focus();
                });             
            }
        });
        },300);
    });
```

Comment: It's bad practice to blindly fire an event on keyup. If you really want a keyup search then you should add a timeout of say 0.5 seconds in javascript and "overwrite it" (clear it and set another one) on the next keyup event. Also abort the previous ajax request if a new one kicks off.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank You for your answer. I understand what you talking about and i wll give a try now. I'll let you know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@apokryfos is exactly right in his comment.

Your `onkeyup` event handler somehow starts a MySQL query: possibly via an ajax-style request from your user's browser to your php page.  Then, before the MyQL query has a chance to finish and return its result set to the browser, the next event handler starts another query.

Once a MySQL query has started (in the usual php implementations), it runs to completion. That's true even if the user closes the browser-to-php connection while the query is in progress.  If your user is capable of kicking off many queries quickly -- by typing fast -- those queries will pile up in the MySQL server until it runs out of resources.

There's a possible vicious cycle here. The user thinks "maybe my request didn't go through" and clicks again, starting yet another request.

The jQueryUI Autocomplete widget has a `delay` parameter to control how often a request gets sent. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay In my experience a setting of one to two seconds yields a high-quality user experience. You may find it helpful to use such a widget; somebody else has already debugged the complexities of javascript timeouts used for delays.